# How to create a different product page structure for specific products under a one category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-view, design

I want to have custom design only for all products which are under a one category. Assume you have category 'A' and it has products 'a','b','c'. I want only to show these 'a,b,c' products in a different structure (design). How to achieve this?

Comment: you mean for products that comes under a specific category?

Comment: I need custom design for products that comes under a particular category

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Comment: The thing is your answer is not actually answering this particular question as I mentioned. But it is good to see how you solve your own problem. There is no offence in that.

Comment: I don't totally avoid your answer. It's one of the proper way of doing this. If I couldn't find the way which I mentioned in my answer, I'll definitely follow yours. But my answer is the simplest thing that can be done at the moment. Thanks again for the responses. Finally got to know two solutions :)

Answer (score 6):

Following solution is done by editing the custom layout update section of the relevant category. Edit yourTheme/template/catalog/product/view-recipe.phtml file to obtain the look you want for the products of the specific category.

> For anyone who is curious about this. The solution was a lot easier
>   than I thought.
>
> I only had to place this piece of code in the custom layout update
>   section of the relevant category and i had to set the option 'Apply to
>   products' to yes!
>
> ```
> <reference name="product.info">
> <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view-recipe.phtml</template></action></reference>
> ```

source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819903/magento-product-view-template-based-on-category

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.

Comment: Can be the answer, the question is not really clear.

Comment: first editing core codes is a big  "NO NO". second your codes looks not clear, means where should it apply. When answer, do it in detail. do you get me friend :-)

Comment: This code must be placed in "the custom layout update section of the relevant category" as precised in the post. The only file that should be edited is myTheme/template/catalog/product/view-recipe.phtml. If i didn't develop my answer it's because i give the link to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry if my question is not clear. But this is not what I expected

Comment: @Lanks : I think you misunderstand me. If you feel my answer is not answering this question correctly, then feel free to downvote it, once you got enough reputation. I still feel this answer is not fit for this question. See my comment on on Sukeshini post. I critic her answer too. I feel her answer is more bad than yours. Because it is not at all an answer for this question. But I didn't downvote her because she is the "FOUNDER" of this question. I repeat.. if you feel my answer is not fit for this question or it is too bad, feel free to downvote. No problem for me. I need our comm more clean

Comment: @Lanks : Also I have tried to upvote your answer once you clarified your answer by your second comment. But I couldn't do that. If you make a small edit on this answer, I would be able to do that :-). I am sure that, this answer is more better than sukeshini

Comment: @programmer_rkt : I'll not down vote your answer since the second solution that you give is correct. Even if my solution is not the best, i don't think it deserve a down vote since it truly allow to change the product's design for a specific category but with some limits. Anyway i should have develop a little more my answer since more explainations was required (my second comment)

Comment: @Lanks : then do it lanks. I am waiting to upvote your answer. I jut need our community better. Just ping me after elaborate your answer :-)

Comment: @Lanks : done. thank for your edit. And it looks better now. Keep answering :-)

Comment: @programmer_rkt : i have edit my answer based on the arguments of my second comment. Maybe my answer will be fine for someone else.

Comment: @Lanks: I have already stated in my answer that this question is not clear. It confuses us whether sukeshini need to customize a category or products. I have commented it first and then decided to answer for both cases. that's it :-)

Comment: @programmer_rkt : I'm glad we succeed to understand each other :) Sure i'll keep answering

Comment: @Lanks : thats the spirit brother. More power to u :-)

Answer (score 6):

This might be the easiest solution possible. Create a new theme and only change the product view page structure in that theme. There's a configuration available in admin panel, which allows you to  assign a theme against a product. See the image below.

[image]

Hope this would be useful for anyone searching for this.

Comment: This is not the "right" answer for your own question. Your question clearly demands that, you need a special look for products that comes UNDER A PARTICULAR CATEGORY. But this answer suits for a question that demands "I need custom product view for a specific product". Both cases are too different. :-)

Comment: programmer_rkt :I edited the question. Only the second solution in your answer maps with what I expected. Thanks for pointing out the weak points :)

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not clear. However if you are looking to customize a particular category, then it is very easy to dot that. Magento generates a specific layout handle for each categories. It will name like `CATEGORY_{ID}`.

So suppose the category id is 22. then create `local.xml` layout file and put your custom design like this

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <CATEGORY_22>  
         <!-- custom design comes here -->
    </CATEGORY_22>
</layout>
```

However if you need custom design for products that comes under a particular category, then there is no easy way to do this as per my knowledge.

One work around is check whether a product belongs to a particular category through an observer. If yes, add a custom `layout handle` to the layout. Later use this custom `layout handle` in order to put your custom designs.

So create an observer like this. (Let me call this module as `Test_Test`)

File : `app/code/local/Test/Test/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <category_product_controller_action_layout_load_before>
                        <class>test_test/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore</method>
                    </category_product_controller_action_layout_load_before>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <test_test>
                <class>Test_Test_Model</class>
            </test_test>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

The event we are observing here is `ontroller_action_layout_load_before`. This is a general event. So we it is important to do some pre checking before further proceeding. Observer somewhat looks like this.

File : `app/code/local/Test/Test/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php

class Test_Test_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //replace this with your category id
        $categoyId = 12;

        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        //ensure product view page
        if ($event->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
            $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

              //make sure product belongs to required categoy
            if (in_array($categoyId, $product->getCategoryIds())) {

                //adding custom layout handle
                $layout = $event->getLayout();
                $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('special_category_product_view');
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Observer will add a custom layout handle `special_category_product_view` if the product that we viewing belongs to a particular category.Now in your layout XML file (you can associate one for this module and then use it. I recommend this. Or use `local.xml`), you can use this handle and specify your custom design there

Hope that will help

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't tryout your answer yet. But it's one of the possible ways to achieve what I want. And +1

Answer (score 0):

Tried the solutions from here, nothing worked for me (magento 1.9.3.4). Found a much simpler solution:

create a *fancy_name*.phtml file in *your_theme*/default/template/page/ (from copy of 1column-product.phtml or something).

Edit *fancy_name*.phtml until it becomes really fancy.

Go to magento backend, go to your product, go to design -> Custom layout update. Paste the following code and save:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/fancy_name.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```